# Using Numpy Arrays to load encoded faces faster in an OpenCV project

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I want to build a simple face recognition project. But Every time I start my program it takes really long time to encode all the Images and the load those encoded images.Can someone please tell me if I can pre-encode all the images and then directly load the encodings. I am a beginner please help me .

I was trying to convert all the faces into numpy arrays but that did not quite workout. But I have a feeling that this is the direction I should go please tell me If I am right or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a comment below.

Comment: If someone did helped you - do not forget to push Up Arrow and Usefull flag on the answer's left. Just a hint.

Comment: You're welllcom. Do to not forget to push Up Arrow and Useful flag beside the good answer. It will make your carma stronger!

Answer (score 0):

In short words: if you already can get face encodings from your images into some data structure, - what a problem to store that data structure permanently for future use?! Use Pickle, some SQL (the simpliest one - sqlite3) or nonSQL database, whatever.

Comment: Yes, after some fiddling around I encountered an encouraging error. 'TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray' . So now I think that all I have to do is somehow store this numpy array and just retrieve that but the question is how? Can you help me by linking some articles. That will certainly be helpful. And Thank you for the comment but I need a little elaboration as I am still a beginner.

Comment: The simpliest way is to use Pickle, the standard Python module for the objects' serialization (store a binary image from memory to disk) and deserialization (load an object to memory from it's bin image at disk file). Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Even more, Numpy has it's own save/load methods to store hardcopies of arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps a lot I will try it out and inform you the results 

Comment: Thanks, the Numpy save/load method worked like a charm 